# highstock chart when loading via ajax has jerky behavior

Tags: ajax, highcharts

I'm using HighStock api and setExtremes callback to load data from server.

When I change the extremes, the whole chart just jerks to some values (x axis changes so do the lines) until the data is returned from the server.

It looks highly unprofessional, as if an error corrected on runtime.

Any change the 'loading' comes and then the new data comes smoothly?

here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/lazy-loading/)

```
if !is_code_accompanied
  stack_overflow = doesnt_let_me_post()
end
```

Comment: Hmm.. how about removing old data before AJAX? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aL2vustj/ - I'm not sure if this is better, since labels on xAxis may change (caused by ordinal axis with irregular interval between points).

Comment: that does look better, but ideally it should JUST show loading on the existing lines (or stacks in this case). For now, this will do, but can't be called the correct answer. Thanks for the insight though.

Comment: I didn't post this as answer, as you can see.. Anyway, let me explain what happens: when changing extremes, we call AJAX, but before it's back, old data is displayed in the background. I don't see **any** reason to hide data in `showLoading()` method. Remember, you can always just remove `opacity` from loader, see: http://jsfiddle.net/aL2vustj/1/. [API reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#loading.style).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
function getDataButNoJerky() {
  ....
  var chart = $('#container').highcharts(); // get our chart
  // if you have multiple series
  for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length - 1; i++) {
    chart.series[i].setData([]);
  }

  chart.showLoading('Loading....');
  // request new data source here
  $.getJSON('/data', function (data) {
    // repopulate your chart with the data returned
  }
}
```

Comment: change your answer slightly to i < chart.series.length - 1 .. and i'd mark it correct ...   that way, navigator series is not changed.